# Atom, incorrect highlighting of nested JSX elements

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, jsx

A question to react/react-native developers who work with atom. I'm getting strange behavior in the editor with nested JSX elements and language-babel package. Take a look at the screenshots. When self-closing component `<Scene/>` is written without a space before slash, the highlighting of opening and closing tags for the parent is ok, but when you add a space (`<Scene />`) the result is not good.
I'm trying to figure out whether it's an atom or language-babel problem, so I can open an issue on github. My best guess, the issue is with language-babel because code folding/unfolding works fine in both cases.
Any ideas?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem in the [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel) package. Specifically in `grammars/Babel Language.json`, under `jsx-tag-element-name`:

```
"end": "\\s*(?<=</)((\\4)|\\2)(>)|(/>)|((?<=</)[\\S ]*?)>",
```

About 2/3 of the way through this regex you'll find this:

```
|(/>)|
```

Which says that as one alternate choice, the end can be `/>` exactly. Note that there is no allowance for whitespace to be here. That is consistent with what you're seeing.

I think the fix is to amend that section of the regex to

```
|(/\\s*>)|
```

In other words, to have the full regex be:

```
\\s*(?<=</)((\\4)|\\2)(>)|(/\\s*>)|((?<=</)[\\S ]*?)>
```

Comment: I changed the expression in `Babel Language.json`, but the behavior is still the same. Sadly my knowledge of regular expressions is very basic yet, but I see your logic. Thank you. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @DavidGevorgyan Did you reload Atom after that change? I'm not sure how much caching Atom does after it is running.

Comment: I did. In fact I tested it on a fresh atom installation, and deleted `~/.config/Atom/Cache` directory after modifying the json file.